# Define a variable at an js import on index.html

Tags: javascript

I have a `JavaScript` script which a user can import on his website.
This script will basicly create an socket connection which transfers small messages which the script will display on the client side.

I will have more than one user on more than one website. So I need an identifier to handle the identification of the website.

I plan to use something like a `CDN` to host this script, so the user can just import it within his `index.html`. The script does always the same logic but with different Connection Values. Im pretty sure I dont have to create the same files, with different identifier values, for every websites which will use my script, but so far i have no idea how to tell the script which identifier value it should use.

**Is there a good way to handle such problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the connection id in the HTML document loading the script, (e.g. `<script src="http://cdn.example.com/your.js" data-connection-id="74893872"></script>`), pull it from the DOM using your JS.

Comment: you might have a sample js snippet to get the value? I would get all elements with script tag and iterate over it to the specific value. But I guess there might be a smarter solution.